# QtJambi5+ Building Process

Tags: java, build, qt5, fedora, qt-jambi

I am trying to build QtJambi5+ from source but I am completely stuck. It seems that something fails after several hours of compiling...

I've got the sources files from here:

https://github.com/OmixVisualization/qtjambi5/wiki/How-to-build-QtJambi

I am supposed to have all requeriments. After some hours I get a failure message like this:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> /opt/qtjambi5/antfiles/java.xml:36: The following error occurred while
> executing this line: /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:4: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:11: The following
> error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:25: The following
> error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:254: Compile failed; see
> the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:571)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:830)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:223)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:284)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:101) Caused
> by: /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:4: The following error
> occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:11: The following
> error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:25: The following
> error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:254: Compile failed; see
> the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:571)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:306)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.SubAnt.execute(SubAnt.java:225)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)   ... 16 more
> Caused by: /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:11: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:25: The following
> error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:254: Compile failed; see
> the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:571)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:106)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)   ... 30 more
> Caused by: /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/QtJambi/build.xml:25: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:254: Compile failed; see
> the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:571)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:440)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)   ... 43 more
> Caused by: /opt/qtjambi5/src/java/qtjambi/modules.xml:254: Compile
> failed; see the compiler error output for details.    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1409)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:1117)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> java.util.Vector.forEach(Vector.java:1277)    at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:67)
> at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:155)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)  at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)     at
> org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1391)
> at
> org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:36)
> at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1254)   at
> org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:437)   ... 55 more

I would appreciate any kind of help to find out where the problem comes out. I am afraid that Java bindings are not so used nowadays and I couldn't find any user with similar problems.

My system is Fedora 32 64bits.